Peer to peer money transfer from one PayPal account to another PayPal
How can I build an app that lets you transfer money from one PayPal account to another PayPal account? Is there any api or sdk provided by PayPal to achieve that task?I know PayPal app already lets you do that, but I need this feature in my app. Your help would be really appreciated.
I searched the PayPal developers site, but couldn’t figure out.

There is no available API to transfer money between accounts that are not yours--and even if one exists for certain PayPal partners there is almost no chance at all that it would be available for you to use.
The most you can do is open a new tab to https://www.paypal.com/sendmoney

I can open a new tab to paypal money transfer url, but how would I know that the transaction was successful. I need a response that would let me know that transaction was successful.

Not possible for that type of send money transaction. If you facilitate a commercial transaction specifying the recipient as the payee, then yes. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/
